# Powershell - Query remote Local Security Policy?

Tags: scripting, powershell, remote-access, security

I am looking to remotely query a list of servers, to ensure they are "set up" correctly

One of the things I want to check is the Local Security Policy -> User Rights Assignment ->Deny Log on through terminal services

Is it possible to retrieve this information through through script?
Using `NTrights` looks to almost get there, but that looks to set or revoke not list permissions.

Most servers I am interested in are Windows Server 2003. I am running PowerShell 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best recommendation I have right now is that you check out using WMI for this (see root\RSOP\computer namespace). Unfortunately all the times that this topic has come up, I never seem to have been able to find a solution to it. There's an old thread on MSDN from 2007 that was never answered either.

You can use SAPIEN WMI Explorer (link below), a free community tool, to browse the WMI namespace and see if what you're looking for is there. I don't believe it is, but you might find some other useful things there.

http://www.primaltools.com/downloads/communitytools/